# Create formula on excel column that all ready have a formula on it

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2010.

I have field A1 and A2.

Field A3 have the following formula

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,A2)
```

Now I want to place a formula on A1 and A2 to make the field background RED with a formula if the Value is not equal to "000".

But I cant add a formula to A1 or A2 now because I am making use of it in field A3.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Unless you are programmatically generating this excel file, your question isn't really suited for this site. Anyway, in Excel you can use Conditional Formatting to do what you want to do.

Comment: Well there is an existing excel Tag, that is why I posted this question here.

Comment: Hmm, well maybe excel formulas are a form of programming too. I hadn't really considered that :-)

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting as @KristofClaes suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Conditional Formatting for this.

1. Select the cells you want to apply the conditional formatting to
2. Click 'Conditional Formatting' and pick 'New Rule...' (Image 01)
3. Select 'Format only cells that contain' (Image 02)
4. Change the criteria to 'Cell Value', 'Not equal to' and '000' (Image 02)
5. Select your formatting (Image 02)

**Image 01**
[image: Conditional Formatting]

**Image 02**
[image: Formatting rule]